# How do you post an array of integers with AFNetworking in objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, afnetworking, nsnumber

This seems like a dumb question, but I'm struggling to post an array of integers within an NSDictionary object (I'm using AFNetworking). That is what the API is expecting so I am restricted to that.

I've got two integer IDs that have been parsed from json responses. Currently, i'm storing these as NSNumber properties, i.e.

```
@property NSNumber id_1;
@property NSNumber id_2;
```

Setting them like this:

```
self.id_1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"id"]]; // id_1 = 300
self.id_2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"id"]]; // id_2 = 301
```

And posting them like this:

```
NSArray *myIDs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.id_1, self.id_2, nil];
NSDictionary *json = @{
                     @"data":@"some data",
                     @"ids": myIDs
                    };
[self.httpClient postPath:@"url.json"
               parameters:json
                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  NSLog(@"success posting");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"failed);
}];
```

This doesn't work since on the API, it appears with the wrong values (I'm getting [78903, 79159])

I can't work out how to build the NSDictionary json object when using NSIntegers, c ints or anything else. What is the correct way to post this array of ids?

Comment: what is the problem with your code? did you get any error, perhaps?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors with this code but the API is showing the wrong values for the integers in the array. I think I should be using NSValue - just trying to work out how to do it.

Comment: WHAT "wrong values"?  And where are you observing these values?  (Show us the JSON.)

Comment: (No, you shouldn't be using NSValue.)

Comment: Hi @HotLicks, the integers I'm adding to the array are 300 and 301. What I get in the API is 78903 and 79159 which look like the pointer addresses cast to integers (or something).

Comment: Your problem is that valueForKeyPath is returning either NSString or NSNumber objects and you are casting those *addresses* to `int`.  Either assign the values without casting (`id1 = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"id"];`) or get the `intValue` from the valueForKeyPath result before you do anything with it.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks, that was exactly the problem. Well spotted and thank you